# C++ Class in class method inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following structure, and I would like to call foo from D. How is it possible? I got the error message, that I commented at the line below.

```
class A
{
protected:
    class B
    {
    public:
        B(x)
        {
            //...
        }

    protected:
        virtual void foo()
        {
            //...
        }
    };
};

class C : public A
{
protected:
    class D : public A::B
    {
    public:
        D(x) : B(x)
        {
            //empty
        }
    };

    void bar()
    {
        D var = D(x);
        var.foo(); //cant access protected member in class A::B
    }
};
```

Comment: Make `foo()` method public?

Comment: Why is this tagged `multiple-inheritance` when there is no multiple inheritance in your code?

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf maybe because there are multiple inheritances in the code ;)

Comment: @tobi303 Clever. You made me doubt actually :)

Comment: that is just pure logic. You can not access protected member outside the class or sub class of it. You are trying to access a member of D from C. C::bar Cant access D::foo. I think what would solve the mistery would be calling foo inside D's constructor. Even instantiating D from C, if inside D constructor, the foo function would be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer. Making the foo function public is really a solution, but I really want foo only available from inherited class. The friend modifier is a thing, what many people hate, because it gives you access for things, thats you should not access.

But also you were right guys, I should access B::foo from D (from constructor is not an option is my case). I could create a function, which calls the original foo, so my solution is:

```
class A
{
protected:
    class B
    {
    public:
        B(x)
        {
            //...
        }

    protected:
        virtual void foo()
        {
            //...
        }
    };
};

class C : public A
{
protected:
    class D : public A::B
    {
    public:
        D(x) : B(x)
        {
            //empty
        }

        Dfoo()
        {
            B::foo();
        }
    };

    void bar()
    {
        D var = D(x);
        var.Dfoo();
    }
};
```

The solution was easy, but I did not know that a function (what is not static) can be called like this :)

Comment: And also B foo doesnt need to be virtual anymore

Answer (score 1):

foo() is protected member function of B, means that foo() is only allowed to be called from its subclass( child class).

bar() is member function of C, and C is inheritance from A. So ,C is not subclass of B.

If you put bar in D, that's OK.As code below:

```
class A
{
protected:
    class B
    {
    public:
        B(int x)
        {
            //...
        }

    protected:
        virtual void foo()
        {
            //...
        }
    };
};

class C : public A
{
protected:
    class D : public A::B
    {
    public:
        D(int x) : B(x)
        {
            //empty
        }

        // Here is OK, while D is subclass of B
        void bar()
        {
            int x;
            D var = D(x);
            var.foo(); //cant access protected member in class A::B
        }
    };

    // void bar()
    // {
    //     int x;
    //     D var = D(x);
    //     var.foo(); //cant access protected member in class A::B
    // }
};


int main(){


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably whatever Iburidu removed to simplify the example for the question would conflict with your solution (The actual `bar` probably needs to be a member of `C`).  If that isn't the case, then `bar` should be a `static` member of `D`, since it clearly shouldn't assume/use a pre-existing object of type `D`

Comment: Oh , yes , I forgot my solution put instance of D in class D itself. Maybe I misunderstand the original idea. Now I think the solution is just putting foo() public .

Answer (score 0):

You might want `foo()` to be public in `D` even though it is protected in `A::B`

If so you can add the following line after the `public:` line in the definition of `D`

```
using A::B::foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a friend class.  You can make D a friend of B, and that should allow D to call foo().

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to access from the class `C` a protected method of the class `D` ==> **You can't** access protected methods from the external of a class.

One solution could be to declare `C` as a **friend class** of `D` so `C` can access protected methods:

```
// ...

    class D : public A::B
    {
    public:
        D(x) : B(x)
        {
            //empty
        }

        // Declare C as friend of D
        friend class C;
    };

// ...
```

Adding the friendship declaration your code will compile and will work as expected.